# How to delete elements and change specific elements in python?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I am writing a Python program to manage FreeRadius user accounts. I can add a new user in my program, but cannot delete users after I entered the target user's username and password. Also, I cannot change the user's password.

How should I change my coding to delete users and provide password changing functions?

```
#!usr/bin/python
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
import os
import subprocess
import commands

main = Tk()

main.title("FreeRadius Windows Administration Controller GUI")
main.geometry('1280x800')

rows = 0
while rows < 50:
     main.rowconfigure(rows, weight=1)
     main.columnconfigure(rows, weight=1)
rows += 1

def startlog():
f = open('C:/FreeRADIUS.net/var/log/radius/radius.log', 'r')
file_contents = f.read()
txtarea_output.insert(INSERT, file_contents)
print (file_contents)
f.close()

def resetlog():
txtarea_output.delete(1.0,END)

def adduser():
fh = open('C:/FreeRADIUS.net/etc/raddb/users.conf', 'a')
fh.write("\n")
fh.write(createuserentry.get() + "     " + "User-Password ==  " + '"' +   createuserpwd.get() + '"')
fh.close()

def deleteuser():
with open('C:/FreeRADIUS.net/etc/raddb/users.conf', "r")
lines = fh.readlines()
with open('C:/FreeRADIUS.net/etc/raddb/users.conf', "a")
for line in lines:
    if deleteuserentry.get() in line:
        continue
        fh.write(line)

def cpwd():
with open('C:/FreeRADIUS.net/etc/raddb/users.conf', "r")
lines = fh.readlines()
with open('C:/FreeRADIUS.net/etc/raddb/users.conf', "a")
for line in lines:
    if changeuserpwd.get() in line:
        continue
        fh.write(line)


nb = ttk.Notebook(main)
nb.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=40, rowspan=39, sticky='NESW')

page1 = ttk.Frame(nb)
nb.add(page1, text='User Account Management')
createuser = ttk.Label(page1, text="Create User").grid(column=0, row=0,     sticky='W')
createusername = ttk.Label(page1, text="Enter new user's   username:").grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='W')
createuserentry = ttk.Entry(page1)
createuserentry.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2)
createuserpassword = ttk.Label(page1, text="Enter new user's password:").grid(column=0, row=2, sticky='W')
createuserpwd = ttk.Entry(page1)
createuserpwd.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=2)
createuserconfirm = Button(page1, text='Create this User', borderwidth=2, command=adduser)
createuserconfirm.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='W')


ttk.Label(page1, text="").grid(column=0, row=4, sticky='W')

deleteteuser = ttk.Label(page1, text="Delete User").grid(column=0, row=5, sticky='W')
deleteusername = ttk.Label(page1, text="Enter current user's username:").grid(column=0, row=6, sticky='W')
deleteuserentry = ttk.Entry(page1)
deleteuserentry.grid(row=6, column=1, columnspan=2)
deleteuserpassword = ttk.Label(page1, text="Enter current user's password:").grid(column=0, row=7, sticky='W')
deleteuserpwd = ttk.Entry(page1)
deleteuserpwd.grid(row=7, column=1, columnspan=2)
deleteuserconfirm = Button(page1, text='Deletete this User', borderwidth=2, command=deleteuser)
deleteuserconfirm.grid(row=8, column=0, sticky='W')

ttk.Label(page1, text="").grid(column=0, row=9, sticky='W')

changepwd = ttk.Label(page1, text="Change User's password").grid(column=0, row=10, sticky='W')
changepwdusername = ttk.Label(page1, text="Enter user's username:").grid(column=0, row=11, sticky='W')
changepwduserentry = ttk.Entry(page1)
changepwduserentry.grid(row=11, column=1, columnspan=2)
changepwduserpassword = ttk.Label(page1, text="Enter user's current password:").grid(column=0, row=12, sticky='W')
changepwduserpwd = ttk.Entry(page1)
changepwduserpwd.grid(row=12, column=1, columnspan=2)
changepwdusernewpwd = ttk.Label(page1, text="Enter user's new password:").grid(column=0, row=13, sticky='W')
changepwdusernewpwd = ttk.Entry(page1)
changepwdusernewpwd.grid(row=13, column=1, columnspan=2)
changepwduserconfirm = Button(page1, text='Change Password',   borderwidth=2, command = cpwd)
changepwduserconfirm.grid(row=14, column=0, sticky='W')
```

Expected Output:

1. User is deleted
2. User's password has been changed

Actual output: Invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

Your code has the following syntax problems:

- No proper indents. Maybe they were removed when you posted code in a question. Anyway, check them;
- your `with` statements missing `as fh` and `:` at their ends

Also there are other problems:

- when deleting or changing config file, you should open it for writing, not for appending, because you will re-create it. So the parameter should be `w`;
- there could be false deletions or changes, because you checks the whole config line for username or password, instead of parsing it and checking exact fields. If some user had a password the same as a name of another user, when you will be deleting that another user, you will delete both. I didn't fix this part of code, leave it for you

Corrected code, untested though, is the following:

---

```
#!usr/bin/python
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
import os
import subprocess
import commands

main = Tk()

main.title("FreeRadius Windows Administration Controller GUI")
main.geometry('1280x800')

rows = 0
while rows < 50:
    main.rowconfigure(rows, weight=1)
    main.columnconfigure(rows, weight=1)
    rows += 1

def startlog():
    f = open('C:/FreeRADIUS.net/var/log/radius/radius.log', 'r')
    file_contents = f.read()
    txtarea_output.insert(INSERT, file_contents)
    print (file_contents)
    f.close()

def resetlog():
    txtarea_output.delete(1.0,END)

def adduser():
    fh = open('C:/FreeRADIUS.net/etc/raddb/users.conf', 'a')
    fh.write("\n")
    fh.write(createuserentry.get() + "     " + "User-Password ==  " + '"' +   createuserpwd.get() + '"')
    fh.close()

def deleteuser():
    with open('C:/FreeRADIUS.net/etc/raddb/users.conf', "r") as fh:
        lines = fh.readlines()
    with open('C:/FreeRADIUS.net/etc/raddb/users.conf', "w") as fh:
        for line in lines:
            if deleteuserentry.get() in line: continue
            fh.write(line)

def cpwd():
    with open('C:/FreeRADIUS.net/etc/raddb/users.conf', "r") as fh:
        lines = fh.readlines()
    with open('C:/FreeRADIUS.net/etc/raddb/users.conf', "w") as fh:
        for line in lines:
            if changeuserpwd.get() in line:
                fh.write(changepwduserentry.get() + "     " + "User-Password ==  " + '"' +   changepwdusernewpwd.get() + '"')
            else:
                fh.write(line)

nb = ttk.Notebook(main)
nb.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=40, rowspan=39, sticky='NESW')

page1 = ttk.Frame(nb)
nb.add(page1, text='User Account Management')
createuser = ttk.Label(page1, text="Create User").grid(column=0, row=0,     sticky='W')
createusername = ttk.Label(page1, text="Enter new user's   username:").grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='W')
createuserentry = ttk.Entry(page1)
createuserentry.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2)
createuserpassword = ttk.Label(page1, text="Enter new user's password:").grid(column=0, row=2, sticky='W')
createuserpwd = ttk.Entry(page1)
createuserpwd.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=2)
createuserconfirm = Button(page1, text='Create this User', borderwidth=2, command=adduser)
createuserconfirm.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='W')

ttk.Label(page1, text="").grid(column=0, row=4, sticky='W')

deleteteuser = ttk.Label(page1, text="Delete User").grid(column=0, row=5, sticky='W')
deleteusername = ttk.Label(page1, text="Enter current user's username:").grid(column=0, row=6, sticky='W')
deleteuserentry = ttk.Entry(page1)
deleteuserentry.grid(row=6, column=1, columnspan=2)
deleteuserpassword = ttk.Label(page1, text="Enter current user's password:").grid(column=0, row=7, sticky='W')
deleteuserpwd = ttk.Entry(page1)
deleteuserpwd.grid(row=7, column=1, columnspan=2)
deleteuserconfirm = Button(page1, text='Deletete this User', borderwidth=2, command=deleteuser)
deleteuserconfirm.grid(row=8, column=0, sticky='W')

ttk.Label(page1, text="").grid(column=0, row=9, sticky='W')

changepwd = ttk.Label(page1, text="Change User's password").grid(column=0, row=10, sticky='W')
changepwdusername = ttk.Label(page1, text="Enter user's username:").grid(column=0, row=11, sticky='W')
changepwduserentry = ttk.Entry(page1)
changepwduserentry.grid(row=11, column=1, columnspan=2)
changepwduserpassword = ttk.Label(page1, text="Enter user's current password:").grid(column=0, row=12, sticky='W')
changepwduserpwd = ttk.Entry(page1)
changepwduserpwd.grid(row=12, column=1, columnspan=2)
changepwdusernewpwd = ttk.Label(page1, text="Enter user's new password:").grid(column=0, row=13, sticky='W')
changepwdusernewpwd = ttk.Entry(page1)
changepwdusernewpwd.grid(row=13, column=1, columnspan=2)
changepwduserconfirm = Button(page1, text='Change Password',   borderwidth=2, command = cpwd)
changepwduserconfirm.grid(row=14, column=0, sticky='W')
```

Comment: After I have copied your code to my program,my program runs again and can delete users,but if I change user's password both the original account and new account with same username and new password are in the users.conf.How can I remove the account with old password when I change a user's password?

Comment: @BobbyWong You didn't copy the change password part correctly. As you could see in the code, there are 2 `fh.write` calls, both under the same `if/else` statement. `if` line in config file matches old password, we write replacement line with the new password, `else` we write an existing line. Most likely your second `fh.write` call has wrong indent and has been executed always

Comment: Then how should I can do?Should I change the second one to f.write()?

Comment: @BobbyWong Just copy/paste block of code exactly as it is written. If it still doesn't work, edit your question and **add** new `def cpwd()` function you got after applied my answer